# php- set a script timeout and call a function to cleanup when time limit reached

Tags: php

I am writing a PHP script that will do some processing, but I only want it to run if the script isn't already running. I also only want the script to run for a maximum of 5 minutes.

I know I can set the timeout using `set_time_limit`, but doing so will not remove the lock files that I create during the execution.

Is their a way to call a function when the time limit is reached so I can perform a cleanup?

Comment: break out of loop, force RE-redirect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried this out in a test environment and got it working with the following (error reporting off + shutdown function):

```
<?php

$test = function() {
    print("\n\nOOPS!\n\n");
};

error_reporting(0);
set_time_limit(1);
register_shutdown_function($test);

while (true) {
}
```

Comment: Note that this will call the shutdown function on any fatal error.  I think that's what you're looking for.  You can also keep error_reporting on if you want, it'll still call the shutdown function.

Comment: Thanks for that. Will the `register_shutdown_function` also be called when I call `exit` throughout my code?

Comment: Don't worry, I just RTFM and it will indeed. Thats great thanks!